# Mixed partials not equal even though function continuous

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the following function:

$$f(x, y) = xy + x^2 + y^2$$

We have the following:

$$\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=y+2x$$

$$\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=x+2y$$

This then gives us the mixed partial derivatives:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}=1\neq2=\dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}}$$

The mixed partial derivatives are not equal, but they should be equal whenever the function is continuous at all points, which seems to be the case.

So either one of the following is the case:

- The function is not continuous
- I am somehow miscalculating the mixed partial derivative
- Or I am misunderstanding the equality theorem for mixed partial derivatives

Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: You have an error (not sure if typo, or actual error), it should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+2y$, which probably confused your next step. The correct answer is $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}=1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Wow you are right, I must have taken the derivative from the wrong one. Thank you so much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because peek-a-boo's comment fully solved the problem.

Comment: You wrote that the mixed partials "should be equal when the function is continuous". If you meant the function $f$, that's not true. If you define $f(x,y)=x y \dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ for most points and $f(0,0)=0$, then $f$ is continuous and the mixed partials are defined, but the mixed partials are not equal. https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math22a2018/exhibits/clairaut/index.html has an animation showing that the mixed partials have opposite sign at the origin.